# JSF : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client-id : _idJsp35 is duplicated in the faces tree in Alfresco Web Client

Tags: jsf, alfresco

I am extending Alfresco Web Client and in one page while expanding panels I get this error. I do not get it always.

```
JSF : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client-id : _idJsp35 is duplicated in the faces tree in Alfresco Web Client
```

I tried to give every component possible unique id, but error still shows up. How can I find source of that error?

Comment: It would help if you posted a stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have seen this it has been due to duplicate ids in your JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you better off not specifying ids, and let JSF do the work for you?